# How can you specify a generic based on the type an extension is applied to?

Tags: swift, generics

Consider the following code which loads a view based on a nib/xib with the same name as the class...

```
extension UIView
{
    static func loadFromNib<T:UIView>() -> T
    {
        let nibName = String(T)
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self)

        return bundle.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! T
    }
}
```

In order to use it, you need to do this...

```
let view:SomeView = UIView.loadFromNib()
```

This way, `T` is inferred to be `SomeView` from the variable it's being assigned to.

However, I'm trying to get it down to this, if possible...

```
let view = SomeView.loadFromXib()
```

...where the type `SomeView` is inferred from the class `loadFromNib` is called on, but I can't figure out how to define the constraint for `T` relative to `self` to support that.

So is this possible?

Comment: I strongly assume that the linked-to Q&A is what you are looking for. Otherwise let me know and I'll reopen the question.

Comment: It isn't.  In that example, Self refers to UIView.  I want whatever refers to SomeView or SomeOtherView provided they are both classes of UIView, which is why I used the generic version.

Comment: Did you try it? With that extension method, `let someView = SomeView.instantiateFromNib()` gives you an instance of `SomeView`, and the type is inferred correctly as `SomeView`.

Comment: I have updated the linked-to answer to make it (hopefully) more clear.

Comment: I stand corrected.  It does work as you stated.  I have to say that was actually a pretty clever use of a private generic like that to get around not being able to cast to Self.  Kudos, and thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, and thanks for confirming it.

Comment: Hey... you may want to explain how you're using that private generic method to get around not being able to explicitly cast to type Self.  That's a pretty neat trick and what I missed when I first looked at it.  Your updated explanation shows that it works, but doesn't explain the 'why' which to me is the really interesting part.